# Sharing Image with Text Story on Facebook Using Facebook SDK 4.1

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.x

I have been struggling with this problem for some time now, I want to simply share a photo with description to facebook using **facebook sdk4.1**. I can share a photo easily using `SharePhotoContent` object.

but it doesn't add description to the photo, so I searched for solutions and it seems that Open graph stories are one solution but it requires much work than this requirement deserve.

Although I tried to find a way to use Open Graph Stories but it requires an action for the story and the available ones doesn't go with my app, so I tried to search for a way to create custom actions but I couldn't.

So please help me with another solution for using open graph stories or provide any tutorial link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Publish Story with Share Dialog through [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/android) and also read how Sharing Open Graph Stories from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#triggering) hope it work for you.

To create and configure custom actions and custom objects for stories [try this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom) and [this](http://elweb.co/facebook-open-graph/).

Best of Luck.

Comment: yeah Grag the problem still would be the action part of the open graph story and I can't find how to make a custom action

Comment: Thanks man, that was useful, I wanted another way than open graph stories but it seems there arn't